# system python versus user python in 2.7

Tags: python, macos, macports

I've installed Python 2.7 using macports and because of my $PATH variable, that's the one I get when I type $ python. However, virtualenv defaults to using Python 2.6 unless I remember to force it to do otherwise with the -p flag.

On a related note, globally running yolk -l shows the following:

Python          - 2.6.1        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload)
So my question is, should I do something to ensure the system is always using MacPorts' Python 2.7 or is it not worth worrying that Apple's Python 2.6.1 is apparently in the mix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$ sudo port select --set python2 python27
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `MacPorts` version as your primary `Python` try:

```
$ sudo port select --set python python27
```

or

```
$ sudo port select --set python2 python27
```

> To make this the default Python or Python 2 (i.e., the version run by
>   the 'python' or 'python2' commands), run one or both.

* Restart Terminal.app, or whichever console you're using then try:

```
$ which python
$ python -V
```